# How to udate attendee inforamtion by using ContentResolver Android?

Tags: java, android

I try to change status for one of attendees for specific Event.

The following example demonstrates how to update event title:

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.TITLE, "Some new title");
String selectedEventId = "123";

    String[] selArgs = new String[]{selectedEventId};
    int updated = cr.update(
                   Events.CONTENT_URI, 
                   values, 
                   Events._ID + " =? ", 
                   selArgs);
```

But I need update information for specific attendee. SO I need somehow to change `Where` part of query.

Right now I have `Events._ID + " =?` that mean *where eventID=123*

and this line will set new type:

```
values.put(Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS, "1"); // 1 - ACCEPTED
```

How to write `where` statement to update specific attendee with email (lets say) `aaa.bbb@gmail.com`

**[EDIT]**

I tried:

```
String selectedEventId = eventStructure.getString("mEventId");
    String selectedEmail = "aaa.bbb@gmail.com";

    String[] selArgs = new String[]{selectedEventId, selectedEmail};
    int updated = 
            cr.
                update(
                   Events.CONTENT_URI, 
                   values, 
                   Events._ID + " =? AND " + Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL + " =?", 
                   selArgs);
```

but get Exception:

```
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: attendeeEmail (code 1): ,
 while compiling: SELECT * FROM Events WHERE _id =? AND attendeeEmail =?
```

Thank you for help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to update attendee information  you need to change `Uri` from `Events.CONTENT_URI` to `Attendees.CONTENT_URI`.

In addition instead `Events._ID` write `Attendees.CONTENT_URI`.

So the snippets of code should be something like:

```
    values.put(Attendees.ATTENDEE_STATUS, "1"); 

    String selectedEventId = eventStructure.getString("mEventId");
    String selectedEmail = "aaa.bbb@gmail.com";

    String[] selArgs = new String[]{selectedEventId, selectedEmail};
    int updated = cr.update(
                Attendees.CONTENT_URI, 
                   values, 
                   Attendees.EVENT_ID + " =? AND " + Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL + " =?", 
                   selArgs);

    Log.d(TAG, "sendAcceptEvent :: updated row count: "+ updated);
```

---

<sub>Didn't test it, but should work</sub>

Comment: Oh, I was too close :).  With some make up, this code works like a charm. Thank you very much.